# How use if/elif/else in create process of new variable in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need create new variable based od existing variable in pandas dataframe. This run ok:

```
xxx = pd.DataFrame({'indsplit': [' km', 11, 12], 'week': [1, 1, 1]})

xxx = xxx.assign(
    week2 = lambda dataframe: xxx['indsplit'].map(lambda indsplit: 10 if indsplit == ' km' 
                                                  else 20) 
)
```

But how can I use more complex logic (if/elif/.../elif/else)? Thanks for the advice.
This end with error:

```
xxx = xxx.assign(
    week2 = lambda dataframe: xxx['indsplit'].map(lambda indsplit: 10 if indsplit == ' km' 
                                                  elif indsplit: 15 if indsplit == 11
                                                  else 20) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to, just define a real function using `def` and pass that instead of using an inline lambda.

```
def mycriteria(indsplit):
    if indssplit == ' km':
        return 10
    if indspllit == 11:
        return 15
    return 20
...
xxx = xxx.assign( week2 = lambd dataframe: xxx['indsplit'].map(mycriteria) )
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is what Im looking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct `if-elif-else` statement in Python lambda function. You can use nested `if-else` instead.

```py
xxx = xxx.assign(week2 = lambda dataframe: xxx['indsplit'].map(lambda indsplit:
                                                               10 if indsplit == ' km'
                                                               else (15 if indsplit == 11
                                                                     else 20))
)
```

You can use a dict instead

```py
d = {
    ' km': 10,
    11: 15,
    12: 20
}

xxx['week2'] = xxx['indsplit'].map(d)
```

To assign a default value to unmatched key, you can use `get` function of dict.

```py
xxx['week2'] = xxx['indsplit'].map(lambda x: d.get(x, 50))
```